# Can a hacker get access to files on hard disk drives of laptop if wireless wifi device gets hacked?

Tags: wifi

I had some private pictures and videos in a folder along with some normal wallpapers. I checked today, and was shocked to find out that only the private pics and videos were not present in the folder, but wallpapers were present.
My wifi device remains connected to the laptop.
What has possibly happened?
Has someone got my private files if they hacked my wifi?
Can a hacker get access to files on hard disk drives of laptop if wireless wifi device gets hacked?
Is it that easy?

The key that's used to connect to the device is written on the device. No one visited my house, so no chance of getting the key that way.

I am using HP I7 with windows 7. Avast antivirus free version is active.
Laptop is password protected.

Comment: Yes. But why are you so sure the problem is a "hacked Wifi device"? There are thousands of more likely things, and a hacked Wifi device itself is multiple distinct possibilities.

Comment: because i dont use that laptop. I only use it to connect the wifi device. Mostly, it remains on the password screen for the user.

Comment: Can you give more details about your infrastructure? Is the laptop used as a hotspot for your other computers? In principle, if someone got themself to your wifi network, it can be possible to access your files

Comment: It is also very unlikely that some one would *move* those files off your drive instead of just copying them. No disrespect, but it sounds like [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK)

Comment: Yes aistesk, it is used as a hotspot for other devices.

Comment: Jan, some of the private files are still there, while 90% are not.

Comment: You could connect to this AP from another device ("Host A") and check if you see the files ("Directory C") that you suspect were accessed by someone. If the AP is not configured to exclusively grant the Directory C's read/write access to Host A and you can see and delete the files, then others connected to the same AP can too.

Comment: All we have to work with is "files are missing, what could have happened?" That's not a lot to work with. Anything is possible, including a variety of non-malicious possibilities.

Comment: aistesk .. no files cannot be seen ..

Comment: One more thing i have realized just now; some pics are duplicated.. i.e. having 2 copies of the same file with different name.. while the rest are only one copy.

Comment: This really does not sound like a case of a hacker attack, from all the provided informations, more like disk failure (given that you state that no-one can have physical access to your laptop).

Comment: I am worried because only private files are gone from 2 sub folders.. why not other files which i have no concern of.. thats why i am astonished by the fact that it is a SELECTIVE DISK FAILURE.

Answer (score 1):

From the information you provided, this might be a hard disk drive failure. You should first check the SMART parameters of the drive. You can then make Windows to try to repair the drive. You can also try software to recover the lost files.

Anyway, you should disable SMB v1 and use a strong password to lock your session. You can use SMB v2. Apply all Windows updates. Then check the permissions of the shared folders: only existing users must be able to connect to the share, using a password.

Comment: Is it possible that only some files disappear in disk failure?

Comment: I depends. If the files that disappeared where in the same directory and the directory got corrupted, yes. Some other specifics of the file systems might have got corrupted, but I do not have enough information from what you provided and I don't know enough about file systems to be able to say more.

If all your files were randomly put in the same folder and just some specific ones where removed, this would suggest a pattern, either done by a human or a software (e.g. a virus infected some files depending on a pattern and your antivirus deleted them afterwards).

Comment: Also, you should not trust your memory. Human memory is highly unreliable. Humans tend to forget memories and sometimes replace them by imagination, unconsciously. Even though unlikely, you might have deleted the files, or you might have given someone the ability to do so.

Comment: I live alone and no one visits me. the memory probability is close to minus. I checked network and file sharing settings ..and it wasnt shared with anyone either. Does it saves from wifi attack? One more thing i have realized ; some pics are duplicated.. i.e. having 2 copies of the same file with different name.. while the rest are only one copy. I am worried because only private files are gone from 2 sub folders.. why not other files which i have no concern of.. thats why i am astonished by the fact that it is a SELECTIVE DISK FAILURE.

Comment: Other than that, is wifi hacking so easy? My password was admin admin.. but the wifi key is written only on the device .. which connects the device to wifi.. waiting for your answers.. 

Comment: (1) You do not provide enough data for us to give you an informed answer to your questions. It could have been a lot of things. (2) WiFi protected by WEP is insecure, you should use WPA-AES with a strong PSK. admin/admin is the first combo I try when I do penetration testing (you could not have chosen a weaker password).

Comment: I donot know what to provide coz i have less knowledge about some deep concepts .. Ask me so I can tell you to conclude ..

Comment: It is protected by WPA2 PSK

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask